# how to iterate on a JsObject and insert a new fields for each object? (play framwork)

Tags: java, json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a simple json:

```
{
  "boys": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "lname": "cross"
    },
    {
      "name": "jack",
      "lname": "silver"
    }
  ],
  "girls": [
    {
      "name": "mary",
      "lname": "kers"
    },
    {
      "name": "jane",
      "lname": "daw"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to take the `boys` list of objects from the json and for each name I want to call a method and add a new field with the value returned from the method to the boys objects...

so I started with something like:

```
// parsing the json above
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(...)

// get the boys
val boys = (json \ "boys").get

// create new boys
val newBoys = ???

// update the json
val updatedJson = json.as[JsObject] + ("boys" -> newBoys)
```

but im not sure how to implement the `newBoys`...

lets say I have a method:

```
def getParentName:(boyName: String) = db.getParent(boyName)
```

so now how can I:

-> iterate on the boys

-> call `getParentName` with the boy name

-> insert a new field to the boy with the value returned

?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want new boys,

```
// create new boys
val newBoys = Json.arr(
  Json.obj("name" -> "boy1", "lname" -> "lboy1"),
  Json.obj("name" -> "boy2", "lname" -> "lboy2")
)

val updatedJson = json.as[JsObject] + "boys" -> newBoys
```

Or, If you want to append to existing boys,

```
// create new boys
val newBoys = boys ++ Json.arr(
  Json.obj("name" -> "boy1", "lname" -> "lboy1"),
  Json.obj("name" -> "boy2", "lname" -> "lboy2")
)

val updatedJson = json.as[JsObject] + "boys" -> newBoys
```